# Print pdf like a book - 2 pages per sheet double sided

Tags: pdf

I have a pdf of a book, I wan't to print it, 2 pages per sheet double sided, so that I can cut the final in half, put the left part above the right part and get the book sorted by order.

How do I do this? Is there a standard way to do it, or a way to change the order of pages in a pdf by a mathematical formula?

Comment: see signatures on using psbook: http://dsl.org/cookbook/cookbook_25.html

Comment: Did you play with the Document Viewer's print dialog? Page setup: two sided, pages per side: 2, then something with page ordering? Sorry, can't test it, I have no printer for double sided printing right now.

Comment: OK this doesn't seem to be so trivial. There are tools for this, like: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/pdfbook.1.html
But there isn't much documentation

Comment: Try importing the PDF into LibreOffice and use the File>Print> Page Layout Tab > Brochure button. Then File > Printer Settings > Properties > Paper > Short Edge.

Comment: @user68186 This should be an answer

Comment: @user68186 I just tried it and it works great, at leas under Ubuntu 16.04.  For me, your comment looks like a perfect answer that can be straightforwardly applied without any extra tools or config required

Answer (score 3):

## 1. Open the PDF file in LibreOffice Draw

Each page will show up as a slide. Use <kbd>Page Down</kbd> and <kbd>Page Up</kbd> keys to navigate between pages. If the book looks OK to print, then proceed to the next step.

## 2. Use the File> Print> Page Layout Tab > Brochure button.

[image]

## 3. Then go to the General Tab > Properties Button

[image]

## 4. Paper Tab > Set the Duplex to **Short Edge** and then press **OK**

[image]

## 5. Press **OK** at the bottom of the **Print** window to print the book.

Hope this helps